# HAproxy double memory usage after reload

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, haproxy

Due to high traffic and nature of our app to keep connections live, our haproxy process consumes good amount of RAM (normally 30-40% of available RAM). Now when we want to add/remove any backend, we have to reload haproxy. During graceful reload (by ubuntu's default init reload), a new haproxy process gets created which will serve new connections and existing process remains there until old connections gets closed by app or cleaned up due to timeout etc. This behaviour is fine.

But both processes almost grab all of available RAM and in fact, things will be scary if first process already consuming more than 50% of RAM then any reload may cause the disruption (haven't experienced yet but increasing traffic will make it happen soon). This forces us to either kill old process by force (losing old connections) or have to keep enough (> 50%) RAM available all the time (wasting resource).

I will appreciate any help/pointer in this context. We are on Ubuntu 12.04 with haproxy 1.4.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem. It's the reason why we support DLMALLOC. Just download it, rebuild haproxy using it and the issue will be gone. That's what we're using in our appliance (ALOHA) for this *exact* reason. Dlmalloc makes use of mmap() to allocate memory and supports holes in its address space, so each call to free() causing at least one page to be released will effectively result in that page to be released. The standard malloc almost does not support this (it tends to support it only when releasing large contigous areas), so it only releases memory once all pages *after* that point are released as well. That's a big difference.